# Cassandra - Keyspace to have unique keynames in each row

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-jdbc

Can I create a column in cassandra , which is dynamic and can be queried ,

For example ,

A customer can have 1 to n addresses ,

Where each address can be referred  like ADDRESS1 (some address) , ADDRES2(some address), ADDRESS3(some address)... ADDRESSN

how can i represent this in cassandra , where i should be able to query a customer or address on particular address also.

Please advise.

Comment: Just use your customerid da the partition key and address numbers as clustering key. May be you can have an id for each address too if you need.

Answer (score 0):

first you create column family with comparator type UTF8Type

```
create column family customerAddress 
with column_type = 'Standard'
and comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';
```

and your representation look like this

customerAddress

```
RowKey: customerId
=> (name=ADDRESS1, value=(some address) , timestamp=1396344612290000)
=> (name=ADDRESS2, value=(some address) , timestamp=1396344612290000)
=> (name=ADDRESS3, value=(some address) , timestamp=1396344612290000)
=> (name=ADDRESS4, value=(some address) , timestamp=1396344612290000)
......
......
=> (name=ADDRESSN, value=(some address) , timestamp=1396344612290000)
```